# How to run a PowerShell script after check in the code to AzureDevOps

Tags: visual-studio

I have a PowerShell script to push a package to AzureDevOps.
I want to run it, automatically, every time that I Check In the code to AzureDevOps in Visual Studio.
Is this possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing package to git in Azure DevOps you can create build pipeline that will execute this package, and this build pipeline will have trigger to run after each commit. 
IF you are pushing packages to Azure DevOps Artifacts then you have option to use Azure DevOps RestApi or Power Shell Module for Azure DevOps and trigger specific build.